# PHP: shell_exec Permissions on Windows Server

Tags: php, shell, windows-server-2012, shell-exec, after-effects

I have the following Problem: If i execute a Shell-Paramter via Shell (cmd.exe) on my ***Windows Server 2012*** it execute perfectly. But if i do the same via PHP (shell_exec) it execute , but with no access to a Template-file.

> *aerender ERROR: No render settings template was found with the given name.*

here is the code

PHP:

```
<?php
chdir('C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects CC 2015\\Support Files\\');
shell_exec('aerender -project C:\server\htdocs\ae\final3\final.aep 
-comp "clouds-   rotation-low" -RStemplate "E2Z640blur" 
-OMtemplate "E2Z640" -output C:\server\htdocs\cache\clouds-rotation-low.avi')  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it works! I just changed the apache2 service in Windows to run as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this happens because when PHP opens up the cmd it doesn't load the PATH variables by standard, I think there is a way around that or you can just use an absolute path for  aerender 
ie. `C:\aerender\aerender`